# sql self join rearrange records for top 4

Tags: python, sql, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am dealing with self join reranking problem but hard to describe it in words. Basically I have a table:

| ID | rank | remove | upgrade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Ture | False |
| 2 | 2 | False | False |
| 3 | 3 | True | False |
| 4 | 4 | False | False |
| 5 | 5 | False | True |
| 6 | 6 | False | False |
| 7 | 7 | False | True |

For the top 4 tows, one row A with remove=true, I want to find the below top 4 nearest row B with upgrade=true. once B is matched to row A, B will not match any rows below A. The new_id will record the id of row B.

For id=1, it needs to be removed, so we go the to below top 4 rows, then id=5 is the first upgradable row, so id=1's new_id=5
for id=3, it needs to be removed, since id=5 already go to id=1's place, the next upgradable row is id=7, so id=3's new_id=7.

So the results table is:

| ID | rank | remove | upgrade | new_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Ture | False | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | False | False | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | True | False | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | False | False | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | False | True | null |
| 6 | 6 | False | False | null |
| 7 | 7 | False | True | null |

I tried self join but cannot figure out the right join condition.

Comment: The logic for `new_id` column is unclear, could you please explain?

Comment: Hi @Dimi, I have added explanations for how new_id comes. thanks for your comments!